# License Manager Option File - How to Checkout/Borrow Specific Licenses?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-license-manager, windows-server-2008

I have a very specific scenario which I want to confirm does NOT work. What I would like to do is allow a specific license to be checked our OR borrowed and for that license I would like this ability to be available to only a specific group of people. To help illustrate I will give a link to the ESRI documentation and I will show the groups and types of licenses I want this accomplished with.

[ESRI Doco here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/license-manager/10.2/index.html#/Using_the_Options_File/00790000000z000000/)

That^ should describe the options file and how to use it. below are the things I have in the options file:

GROUP CartoGroup tzjohn epnewto gdtowse plulare fastuar kgjaela

GROUP EnginGroup pbgreld hjcruco rrdale dljacob tjhobsi

RESERVE 4 VIEWER GROUP CartoGroup

RESERVE 3 VIEWER GROUP EnginGroup

Now the above license server stores licenses from two different business groups. Their licenses belong to their group only and are NOT to be shared between each group. There are 7 Viewer licenses installed on the license server. What I want is for the CartoGroup to be able to BORROW two licenses however I want their 4 licenses to still only be reserved for them to be checked out. So I would think that the below configuration is closest to what I would want but it won't work.

GROUP CartoGroup tzjohn epnewto gdtowse plulare fastuar kgjaela

GROUP EnginGroup pbgreld hjcruco rrdale dljacob tjhobsi

RESERVE 4 VIEWER GROUP CartoGroup

RESERVE 3 VIEWER GROUP EnginGroup

INCLUDE_ENTITLEMENT EFL546888774-1010 GROUP CartoGroup

INCLUDE_ENTITLEMENT EFL224676441-1010 GROUP CartoGroup

The reason why the above settings won't work is because tzjohn and epnewto can BORROW a license which means their group is using two licenses. Then all the other users in the group could check out up to 4 licenses as well which leaves a total of 6 licences being used by the CartoGroup! The CartoGroup needs to only have access to BORROW/CHECK OUT up 4 licenses as once combined.

Does anyone know how to configure the options file so I can allow borrowing and checking out licenses for ONE group up to the amount of licenses they own?

Server: Windows 2008 r2

ArcGIS Server 10.2.2

ArcMap 10.2.2

Comment: Let me know if you need more clarification on the issue.

Comment: It is clear to me now that it is not possible with the current License Manager. I have created a post in ArcGIS Ideas for the issue so please go to the link and Promote/upvote it if you want this functionality - http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E0000000CvCxIAK

Comment: I think that you should post your comment as an answer.